# TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined at guild.members

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I need help with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined".

```js
            let members = guild.members.cache
                .filter(function (member) {
                    return member.user.bot === false && member.user.id != member.guild.ownerID;
                })
                .map(function (member) {
                    return { id: member.user.id, nickname: member.nickname, member: member };
                });
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined at /root/isac/sachi.js:251:33 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) at async Client. (/root/isac/sachi.js:248:7)

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: Also post the full error message. Which variable is undefined in the code, and where does it come from?

Comment: `guild.members` is undefined - where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

defined `let members = [];`
removed `let` in `let members = message.guild.members.cache.filter(fun...` added `message.` in front of `guild.members.cache.filter(functi...`

because guild is not my guild, I was asking something not mine.

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to fully answer the question without knowing more about the problem, like what are other packages that you are using and the rest of the code.

By looking at the code you have provided the answer is there when you read the error message.

`"TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined"`

Cache is a property of `guild.members`

And there is no such property called `cache` because there is no such object as `members` in `guild`

Since there is no such property as `members` it is `undefined` and you can't read a property called `cache` in an undefined object.

I suggest you to check what's returning in `guild` and to see if there is a `members` objects

```
console.log(guild)
```

And see the output.

Comment: when i use 
console.log(guild)

i get the list of available members in the server but it just get undefined at the members = guild.members....